# tabularray: \linewidth does not consider colsep in multi-column cells

Tags: tables, width, tabularray, linewidth

Maybe I am overlooking something, but it seems that in a `tblr` environment, `\linewidth` behaves differently depending on whether it is used in a cell that spans multiple columns or not.

Consider the following MWE: I placed a rule with the width of `\linewidth` into each of the cells. Also, I set the column padding to `5pt`. In the first example, `\linewidth` obviously takes the column padding into account and the rules exactly fit into the cells.

In the second example, I added a multi-column cell that spans over both columns. Here we get a warning regarding an overfull box that is exactly twice the column padding. Hence, it seems that `\linewidth` in this context does not take the column padding into account.

The same seems to hold for the width of vertical borders: If `\linewidth` is used in a multi-column cell, we get an overfull-box warning for the sum of the column paddings and the border widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray, xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = { X X },
    columns = {colsep = 5pt, lightgray},
}
\rule{\linewidth}{2pt} & \rule{\linewidth}{2pt} \\ 
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

% multi-column cell
\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = { X X },
    columns = {colsep = 5pt, lightgray},
    cell{2}{1} = {c = 2}{},
}
\rule{\linewidth}{2pt} & \rule{\linewidth}{2pt} \\ 
\rule{\linewidth}{2pt} \\ % Overfull \hbox (10.0pt too wide)
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

% multi-column cell plus borders
\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = { | X X | },
    columns = {colsep = 5pt, lightgray},
    cell{2}{1} = {c = 2}{},
}
\rule{\linewidth}{2pt} & \rule{\linewidth}{2pt} \\ 
\rule{\linewidth}{2pt} \\ % Overfull \hbox (10.8pt too wide)
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wonder whether this a bug or intended behaviour. Anyways, the only way to solve this that comes to my mind, would be to explicitly set `cell{2}{1} = {c = 2}{wd=...}`. Does the package provide a more elegant solution?

Comment: the elegant solution is to make a bug report ;-)

Comment: but actually I'm not sure if \linewidth is really supported in a multicolumn cell, if one restrict the tabular it is still equal to the outside linewidth.

Comment: The first row is set in paragraph mode by the `X` column type and the width of the paragraph sets `\linewidth`, whereas the multicolumn cell is not set in paragraph mode (which you can verify just by typing a lot of text instead: it won't wrap), so `\linewidth` remains that of the surrounding paragraph environment. You could set the width `cell{2}{1} = {c = 2}{wd=3in}` and then it would be in paragraph mode too, but knowing what to set the width isn't any easier than knowing what `\linewidth` *should* be.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer True! If you have three columns a cell spanning two columns with the width of `\linewidth` will still be as wide as the outside `\linewidth` pushing the third column outside the surrounding text frame.

Comment: @frabjous Thanks. This pretty much explains what's going on and also suggests that there is no real elegant solution for it (apart from using `2\tabcolsep` instead of explicit widths perhaps). I did not realize up to now that this problem actually applies to other tabular environments too.

Comment: but you could open an issue anyway. tabularray should be able to offer an interface for the width.

Comment: Thank you vey much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After skimming through the package code, I found that the inner width of the current box is stored in a macro named `\l__tblr_cell_wd_dim`. So, literally one single line of code is actually needed to make the value stored in this macro accessible outside of `expl3` syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray, xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cellwidth}{ }{
    \l__tblr_cell_wd_dim
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
        colspec      = { X X X }, 
        columns      = { colsep = 5pt },
        cell{3-4}{1} = { c = 3 }{},
        cell{5-6}{1} = { c = 2 }{},
        hlines, 
        vlines
    }
    
    \rule{\cellwidth}{2pt} & \rule{\cellwidth}{2pt} & \rule{\cellwidth}{2pt} \\
    \the\cellwidth         & \the\cellwidth         & \the\cellwidth         \\
    
    \rule{\cellwidth}{2pt}                                                   \\
    \the\cellwidth                                                           \\
    
    \rule{\cellwidth}{2pt}                        & & \rule{\cellwidth}{2pt} \\
    \the\cellwidth                                & & \the\cellwidth         \\
    
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]